# Long to wide: turn one column into two in R without for loops

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame with a column called Var that looks like this:

```
Var   Value
a     1.5
b     2.5
c     3
Red   4
Green 4.5 
Blue  0.5
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Color Var   Value
Red   a     1.5
Red   b     2.5
Red   c     3
Red   Red   4
Green a     1.5
Green b     2.5
Green c     3
Green Green 4.5
Blue  a     1.5
Blue  b     2.5
Blue  c     3
Blue  Blue  0.5
```

In other words, I want to repeat all non-color values of Var for each color value of Var. Is there a quick and neat way to do this while avoiding for loops?

Comment: That doesn't look like [tidy data](https://ramnathv.github.io/pycon2014-r/explore/tidy.html). What are you planning to do with it? There might be a better / more tidy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @Roman Luštrik's solution, but slightly easier (in my opinion):

```
df <- read.table(text='Var   Value
a     1.5
b     2.5
c     3
Red   4
Green 4.5 
Blue  0.5', header=TRUE)

cols <- c('Red', 'Green', 'Blue')

do.call(rbind, lapply(cols, function(col, df){
  df[, 'Color'] <- col
  df[!(df$Var %in% cols) | df$Var == col,]
}, df=df))[, c('Color', 'Var', 'Value')]
##    Color   Var Value
## 1    Red     a   1.5
## 2    Red     b   2.5
## 3    Red     c   3.0
## 4    Red   Red   4.0
## 11 Green     a   1.5
## 21 Green     b   2.5
## 31 Green     c   3.0
## 5  Green Green   4.5
## 12  Blue     a   1.5
## 22  Blue     b   2.5
## 32  Blue     c   3.0
## 6   Blue  Blue   0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach. It basically involves creating two `list`s which we can then "bind" together with `mapply`.

```
library(data.table) ## for rbindlist -- fast simple syntax

cols <- c('Red', 'Green', 'Blue')
CR <- df[df$Var %in% cols, ]   ## Color rows...
CR <- split(CR, 1:nrow(CR))    ## ... split into a list
## The other rows, replicated into a list
OR <- replicate(length(CR), df[!df$Var %in% cols, ], FALSE)

bindFun <- function(x, y) cbind(Color = y[[1]][1], rbind(x, y))

rbindlist(mapply(bindFun, OR, CR, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
#     Color   Var Value
#  1:   Red     a   1.5
#  2:   Red     b   2.5
#  3:   Red     c   3.0
#  4:   Red   Red   4.0
#  5: Green     a   1.5
#  6: Green     b   2.5
#  7: Green     c   3.0
#  8: Green Green   4.5
#  9:  Blue     a   1.5
# 10:  Blue     b   2.5
# 11:  Blue     c   3.0
# 12:  Blue  Blue   0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I created a vector of colors and made a data.frame for each color by appending non-colors rows to one particular color.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "Var   Value
a     1.5
b     2.5
c     3
Red   4
Green 4.5 
Blue  0.5", header = TRUE)

cols <- c("Red", "Green", "Blue")

do.call("rbind", 
        sapply(cols, function(x, cols, xy) {
          nocols <- xy[!xy$Var %in% cols, ]
          rbind(nocols, xy[xy$Var %in% x, ])
        }, cols = cols, xy = xy, simplify = FALSE)
        )

          Var Value
Red.1       a   1.5
Red.2       b   2.5
Red.3       c   3.0
Red.4     Red   4.0
Green.1     a   1.5
Green.2     b   2.5
Green.3     c   3.0
Green.5 Green   4.5
Blue.1      a   1.5
Blue.2      b   2.5
Blue.3      c   3.0
Blue.6   Blue   0.5
```

Comment: This is so close to what I need! If there was a way to allow duplicated rownames this would be perfect. I, unfortunately, cannot just gsub() the numbers out of the rowname because my colors may have decimals and numbers in the name.